# Facebook Page Stats (when it's not your page)

Tags: facebook, statistics

I am trying to do a research paper for a company, and I need to look at their competitors' Facebook basic stats. I am wondering is there a service or a Facebook link that will show me how many likes a page has?

I understand I won't be able to get a break-down of those stats which is fine. But I noticed these pages I am trying to get the basic stats for have either hidden the stat or Facebook no longer shows it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the insights stats of the pages by issueing requests to the

```
/{page_id}/insights/page_fans_country?access_token={app_access_token}
/{page_id}/insights/page_storytellers_by_country?access_token={app_access_token}
```

You need at least an **App Access Token** for being able to request the stats:

> Any valid access token can be used for publicly available metrics (currently `page_fans_country` or `page_storytellers_by_country`).

An example output for the `CocaCola` page would be in the first case (replace `{app_access_token}` and `{page_id}` with real values):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
          "value": {
            "BR": 7647998, 
            "US": 5235912, 
            "MX": 2226214, 
            "PH": 1580316, 
            "AR": 1470243, 
            "FR": 1318475, 
            "IN": 1216773, 
            "TH": 1152195, 
            "GB": 1045901, 
            "IT": 929906, 
            "ID": 751678, 
            "EG": 751109, 
            "ES": 743127, 
            "CO": 696836, 
            "AU": 691082, 
            "TR": 637989, 
            "CL": 563704, 
            "DE": 541448, 
            "PL": 520851, 
            "PK": 460125, 
            "VE": 447073, 
            "VN": 442866, 
            "IQ": 432159, 
            "PT": 431431, 
            "CA": 400651, 
            "RO": 388648, 
            "KH": 370813, 
            "PE": 335064, 
            "EC": 303637, 
            "BD": 282001, 
            "TW": 266267, 
            "PR": 250198, 
            "TZ": 245476, 
            "UY": 238471, 
            "MA": 232024, 
            "IE": 230698, 
            "BG": 227318, 
            "HR": 223257, 
            "ET": 213823, 
            "BO": 209638, 
            "MK": 202446, 
            "KR": 202340, 
            "CH": 196162, 
            "SA": 189885, 
            "UG": 187797
          }, 
          "end_time": "2015-06-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Likes by Country", 
      "description": "Lifetime: Aggregated Facebook location data, sorted by country, about the people who like your Page. (Unique Users)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country?debug=all&limit=1&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1432716363&until=1432975563", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/cocacola/insights/page_fans_country?debug=all&limit=1&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1433234763&until=1433493963"
  }
}
```

Furthermore, you can request the overall Page's stats via

```
/{page_id}?fields=id,name,likes,talking_about_count,were_here_count&access_token={app_access_token}
```

This will result in

```
{
  "id": "40796308305", 
  "name": "Coca-Cola", 
  "likes": 90712576, 
  "talking_about_count": 345288, 
  "were_here_count": 0
}
```

for the `CocaCola` page.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/insights#reading
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Reading